# Why don't the comments appear instantly in my React app project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I am working on my very first React application and i got stuck trying to create a comment section for a blog. Whenever i leave a comment under a post, it doesnt appear instantly but after i've refreshed or returned to the page.
In my console they do show up instantly.
Can anyone help me solve this?

**CommentAdd**

```
function CommentAdd(props) {

    const {handleCommentSubmit} = props;

    const [comment, setComment] = useState('');

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="card mt-4 mb-3">
                <div className="card-header"><strong>Comments</strong></div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <textarea name="comments" className="form-control" placeholder="Add a new comment"
                              onChange={event => setComment(event.target.value)} value={comment}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary mr-3" onClick={event => {
                    handleCommentSubmit(comment);
                    setComment('');
                }}>Comment</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CommentAdd;
```

**CommentGroup**

```
class CommentGroup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            body: [],
            postId: props.postId,
            storyParts: props.storyParts || [],
            datePublished: new Date(),
            isLoaded: false
        }

        this.handleCommentSubmit = this.handleCommentSubmit.bind(this);

    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.setState({comments: this.props.comments});

    }

    handleCommentSubmit(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        const postData = {
            body: data,
            postId: this.state.postId,
            datePublished: new Date(),
        };

        console.log(postData)

        axios.create(postData).then((response) => {
            console.log('response', response.data);
            let comments = this.state.comments;
            if (response.data)
                comments.unshift({
                    id: response.data.storyId,
                    body: response.data.body,
                    localDate: response.data.localDate,
                })
            this.setState({comments: this.props.comments});
        });
    }

    renderComments() {
        return this.props.comments.map((comment, index) => {
            const {finishStoryId, storyId, body, localDate} = comment;
            return (
                <Comment key={index} storyId={storyId} body={body} localDate={localDate} finishStoryId={finishStoryId}/>
            );

        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderComments()}
                <CommentAdd handleCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CommentGroup;
```

Comment: You are mixing `this.state.comments` and `this.props.comments` quite a bit in `CommentGroup`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes that was done intentional

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two issues. First, when setting the new state from the API response, you should set the value to the updated `comments` variable.

```js
this.setState({ comments: comments });

// Or using the object literal shorthand
this.setState({ comments })
```

Next, in your `renderComments` function, you should be using `this.state.comments` instead of `this.props.comments`.

```js
return this.state.comments.map((comment, index) => {
```

Comment: I just tried it, but i'm getting   TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Is it related to the `if (response.data)` conditional?  If your API returns undefined in some circumstances you'll likely need to update your conditional to also wrap the `this.setState` function call.

Answer (score 0):

I saw in your code:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.setState({comments: this.props.comments});
}
```

My assumption is, the `comments` has been passed to `CommentGroup` as prop, if it is your scenario. You do not need to set the comments to `CommentGroup` state.

You should pass the function `updateComments` to `CommentGroup` as well, the `CommentGroup` parent should look like below:

```
class CommentGroupParent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      comments: []
   }
  }

  updateComments = (comment) => {
    this.setState({ comments: [comment, ...this.state.comments]})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CommentGroup comments={this.state.comments} updateComments={this.updateComments} />
    )
  }
}
```

in your `CommentGroup` code:

```
// ... your code
comments.unshift({
  id: response.data.storyId,
  body: response.data.body,
  localDate: response.data.localDate,
})
this.setState({comments: this.props.comments});
```

should be replaced by

```
this.props.updateComments({
  id: response.data.storyId,
  body: response.data.body,
  localDate: response.data.localDate,
})
```

**Additonal information**

Updating state like below is anti pattern:

```
let comments = this.state.comments;

comments.unshift({
  id: response.data.storyId,
  body: response.data.body,
  localDate: response.data.localDate,
});
this.setState({ comments: this.props.comments });
```

To update state, you should not use `unshift` even on the new variable that assigned to a piece of state, it still leads to unpredictable state changes, your code should be changed like below:

```
this.setState({
  comments: [
    {
      id: response.data.storyId,
      body: response.data.body,
      localDate: response.data.localDate,
    },
    ...this.state.comments
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are making some antipatterns. First you are replicating props to state like here:

```
    this.state = {
        postId: props.postId, // don't do this
        storyParts: props.storyParts || [],
    }


async componentDidMount() {
    await this.setState({comments: this.props.comments}); // this is also bad

}
```

another thing you should never do is mutating state like directly:

```
            comments.unshift({
                id: response.data.storyId,
                body: response.data.body,
                localDate: response.data.localDate,
            }) // when dealing with arrays/objects create copies instead modifying then
```

given you pass down `this.props.comments`, you should also pass down a setState function prop (something like `updateComments`) to update comments state that lies in some upper parent. your axios post should look something like:

```
    axios.create(postData).then((response) => {
        console.log('response', response.data);
        if (response.data)
          const comment = {
                id: response.data.storyId,
                body: response.data.body,
                localDate: response.data.localDate,
            }
        this.props.updateComments(comment);
    });
```

and `this.props.updateComments` will be a function defined at the root location of comments, where it's responsible to handle update comments properly:

```
 // this function lies at root component where comments lies. you pass down accordingly
 updateComments = (comment) => this.setState(({ comments }) => ([comment, ...comments]))
```

remember to use only **one single source of truth**. don't duplicate props to state, and don't mutate state directly.

**extra**

when render with **map** use some id from the giving comment to pass as key. passing `index` it may creates troubles to react tracker properly your array when you perform changes on it.